# What congressional committees' jurisdiction US entertainment industry, e.g. Hollywood, falls under?

Tags: united-states, congress

I googled extensively but found little certainty about US entertainment industry's oversight by US Congress. The [Senate Committee on Commerce, Science, and Transportation](https://www.commerce.senate.gov/jurisdiction) website explicitly states that sports industry falls under the committee's jurisdiction. But I found no mention of a similar industry - entertainment (Hollywood) - in either Senate or House jurisdictions. However, some states, like California, have specific committees on arts and movies. Can you clarify which US congressional committees - both in Senate and House - have jurisdiction over entertainment industry?

Comment: The [1993 hearings on violence in video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_United_States_Senate_hearings_on_video_games) were held jointly by the Senate Committee on Governmental Affairs and the Senate Committee on the Judiciary.  So there's one data point.

Comment: And in 1985, the Senate Committee on Commerce, Science, and Transportation held [hearings on explicit lyrics in music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parents_Music_Resource_Center#Senate_hearing) .  So there's another data point.

Answer (score 4):

*Can you clarify which US congressional committees - both in Senate and House - have jurisdiction over entertainment industry?*

There is no specific committee, in either the House or Senate, for which the jurisdiction of the entertainment industry falls. Instead, it is necessary to to focus on particular aspects of the industry, for example, copyrights, labor, distribution, etc.

The jurisdictions of each committee are given in the rules of each body.

- House of Representatives, [Rule X](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-CLERK-RULE-PAMPHLET-117/xml/GPO-CLERK-RULE-PAMPHLET-117.xml), Committees and their legislative
  jurisdictions
- Senate, [Rule XXV](https://www.rules.senate.gov/rules-of-the-senate), Standing Committees

Intellectual property rights (copyrights) fall within the Judiciary committees of both the House and Senate. Most other matters fall within the respective committees for Labor or Commerce.

[S.167 - Family Entertainment and Copyright Act of 2005](https://www.congress.gov/bill/109th-congress/senate-bill/167) in the 109th Congress was referred to the Committees: "Senate - Judiciary | House - Judiciary; House Administration". The bill became law.

[H.R.3691 - Child Performers Protection Act](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/3691) in the 115th Congress was "Referred to the House Committee on Education and the Workforce." For the 117th Congress that would be the House Committee on Education and Labor. The bill died in committee.